# How to use multiple rich Text toolbar in list adapter?

Tags: android

I'm trying to create rich Text on my project by this library from this git:
[RTEditor](https://github.com/1gravity/Android-RTEditor)

The problem is that i'm tring to create it multiply times like in a listView with many richText toolbar and EditText. any idea how to to it?